I want to write the string "1234" to a cell using Google Apps Script. (Google Spreadsheets)
I have a question about Google Spreadsheets.
When I execute the following code in Google Apps Script, "number" is displayed in the console and "string" is not displayed in the console.
I want to write the string "1234" to the cell.
function myFunction() {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  const cell = sheet.getRange(1, 1);
  cell.setValue(String(1234));
  let a = cell.getValue();
  console.log(typeof a);
}


Try:
function myFunction() {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  const cell = sheet.getRange(1, 1);
  cell.setValue(1234).setNumberFormat('@');
  let a = cell.getValue();
  console.log(typeof a);
}

Number format tokens

Boris Baublys, thank you very much for your perfect answer!
